# Ошибка в форме для регистрации

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Ошибка в том, что я пытаюсь конвертировать объект в строку и не могу понять, как сделать правильно.
Вот мой код:

```
users.php
public function create(){
        global $database;

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username , password , first_name , last_name)
        VALUES ('$database->$this->username','$database->$this->password','$database->$this->first_name','$database->$this->last_name')";
        if($database->query($sql)) {
            $this->id = $database->insert_id();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

и в тестовом фалйе я пытаюсь подставить данные :

```
 test.php
<?php
    require_once('../../includes/initialize.php');
    if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); }


    include_layout_template('admin_header.php'); 


        $user = new Users();
        $user->username = "ValeraTkachenko";
        $user->password = "1111";
        $user->first_name = "Valera";
        $user->last_name = "Tkachenko";
        $user->create();



     include_layout_template('admin_footer.php');
```

Ошибка возникает на моменте `VALUES ('$database->$this->username'...`  что я пытаюсь конвертировать объект в строку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно подправить. Спасибо

Comment: ничего не понял, но такое чувство, что вот этот фрагмент `->$this` вы используетет неправильно

Answer (score 1):

И правда проблема была в переменной $database её можно было просто убрать и всё сразу заработает.